# How do I find the size of the L1 cache lines from within a Java process?

Tags: java, caching, cpu

I am interested in fine-tuning cache-conscious data structures (see for example the lock-free skip tree in [Michael Spiegel's dissertation](http://mspiegel.github.io/publications/michael-spiegel-dissertation.pdf) or Herlihy et al's [hopscotch hashing](http://mcg.cs.tau.ac.il/projects/hopscotch-hashing-1)) as well as in preventing [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) e.g. during concurrent array processing.  I already know how to find the JVM pointer size via the "sun.arch.data.model" property, but I haven't been able to find a way to determine the size of cache lines in the L1 cache.

Note that this information isn't critical, as I can just continue to use conservative estimates for the L1 line size (64 bytes when fine-tuning cache-conscious data structures, or 256 bytes when preventing false sharing); however if it's easy to acquire the L1 cache properties then I may as well make use of it.

Comment: I think this (very interesting, I'd even say exciting) task would cost way too much to implement. I would do the lazy thing here: hardcode cache sizes for CPU models, and determine that - as it might happen to be easier. However, this could go wrong if the JVM is run inside a VM of some kind which hides the actual CPU model, whereas your solution would use the correct sizes for that scenario...

Comment: The line size is the line size; in what sense is it ever 64 **and** 256?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If I don't know the precise line size then I use different estimates depending on what I'm trying to accomplish, e.g. if I'm fine-tuning a cache-conscious data structure then I'll use the lower estimate of 64 bytes because this way the data structure will still perform well if the actual line size is greater than 64 bytes, and if I'm preventing false sharing then I'll use the higher estimate of 256 bytes because this will still perform well if the actual line size is less than 256 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is a simple loop that reads single bytes from memory at a given stride. if the stride is 1 (byte), than you you would have to pay a line fetch penalty once every  iterations. if you double the skip, you could expect half the performance since you now fetch a line twice per the same number of iterations.

Once you reach the cacheline size with your strides, you should see the perf degradation stop, since you would reach the level where you fetch a line once per iteration, and doubling the stride again won't change it, you'd just skip lines. One problem with that is that you may trigger a HW stream prefetchers in your CPU, and have the lines waiting for you at in advance at some lower cache level, so i'd expect to see the slope diminish, but not straighten up completely. At a stride of twice the cache line size this may disappear as you could shake of some of the stream prefetchers by being faster than them (there could still be stride prefetchers "helping" you further, but the impact should be dramatically smaller).

Also keep in mind that your code should run over a data set (an array for e.g.) bigger than the last level cache, a few MBs should suffice.